# Multi-threading em aplicações PHP

Tags: php, multithreading

Existe algum design pattern para realizar a execução de multiplos processos e a coleta dos resultados no mesmo?

Cenário:
Eu tenho um grande volume de dados (> 200000 entradas), tenho que executar verificações recursivas neles e também reduzir o tempo de execução decorrido(e claro sem causar timeout). Qual seria a melhor solução?

Multi-threading é uma opção? Existe uma maneira realista de implementar um modelo multi-threaded em PHP?

Comment: se o volume de dados é grande. Não é melhor trabalhar eles fora da requisição e notificar ao usuário quando o processamento deles serem concluídos? Um exemplo é o facebook quando você envia um vídeo, ele libera o usuário e quando o vídeo acaba de ser processado ele manda uma notificação.

Comment: Eu poderia criar uma API e processar em lotes também, mas a principal dúvida ainda é sobre o uso/existencia de multithreading.

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer encontrei um artigo que pode te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications.
Espero haja um boa resposta e sobre um padrão talvez o RxPHP possa ajudar: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPHP

Comment: Cheguei a encontrar essa pergunta e estou testando algo em torno do pthreads agora, mas vou dar uma olhada no RxPHP também

Comment: Dá uma lida em Parallel ([php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.parallel.php),[packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/amphp/parallel)). Ele tem mais suporte da comunidade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Multi-threading é possível em php**

Sim você pode fazer multi-threading em PHP com [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads).

**Da [documentação do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pthreads.php):**

> pthreads é uma API orientada a objetos que fornece todas as ferramentas necessárias para multi-threading no PHP. Aplicativos PHP podem criar, ler, escrever, executar e sincronizar com objetos Threads, Workers e Threaded.
>
> Atenção : A extensão pthreads não pode ser usada em um ambiente de servidor da web. Threading em PHP deve, portanto, permanecer apenas para aplicativos baseados em CLI.

```
<?php
class OperacaoAssincrona extends Thread {

    public function __construct($arg) {
        $this->arg = $arg;
    }

    public function run() {
        if ($this->arg) {
            $sleep = mt_rand(1, 10);
            printf('%s: %s  -start -sleeps %d' . "\n", date("g:i:sa"), $this->arg, $sleep);
            sleep($sleep);
            printf('%s: %s  -finish' . "\n", date("g:i:sa"), $this->arg);
        }
    }
}

// Criar um array
$stack = array();

//Inicializando multiplas Thread
foreach ( range("A", "D") as $i ) {
    $stack[] = new OperacaoAssincrona($i);
}

// iniciar a Threads
foreach ( $stack as $t ) {
    $t->start();
}

?>
```

Primeira execução

```
12:00:06pm:     A  -start -sleeps 5
12:00:06pm:     B  -start -sleeps 3
12:00:06pm:     C  -start -sleeps 10
12:00:06pm:     D  -start -sleeps 2
12:00:08pm:     D  -finish
12:00:09pm:     B  -finish
12:00:11pm:     A  -finish
12:00:16pm:     C  -finish
```

Segunda Opção

```
12:01:36pm:     A  -start -sleeps 6
12:01:36pm:     B  -start -sleeps 1
12:01:36pm:     C  -start -sleeps 2
12:01:36pm:     D  -start -sleeps 1
12:01:37pm:     B  -finish
12:01:37pm:     D  -finish
12:01:38pm:     C  -finish
12:01:42pm:     A  -finish
```

Esse é um modelo de como usar Multi-threading.

Mas um designer pattern muito bom é [RxPHP](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPHP) acho que vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Referência da resposta:
[How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)